# Graph nodes pushed to top left corner of svg

Tags: d3.js

I'm teaching myself D3 to graph some data that i've collected and processed for a project of mine. I believe i have the foundations of D3 down, so i decided to start creating my own Scatterplot. So, along with some test data, i've made some code that plots dots to the screen (well, it should). It prints out the elements of the chart, but they are all situated at the top left of the svg.

Can anyone provide some assistance and help me understand why it has done this? I couldn't find any similar posts on SO.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var data = [[0.3,0.3], [0.10, 0.10], [0.4, 0.4], [0.8, 0.8]];

var w = 500;
var h = 300;
var padding = 20;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append("svg")
    .attr('width', w)
    .attr('height', h)

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d[0]; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d[1]; });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `data` coordinates are very small (less than 1 pixel). Try using bigger values: `var data = [[30,30], [100, 100], [40, 40], [80, 80]];`

Comment: Why is this? As those small values are duplicates of data i'd be using in the visualisation... Is there a way to use the values i have without it floating to the top left? Or can i scale them in anyway, but have the values represented as 0.8, 0.1, etc?

Comment: Indeed, a scale is recommended in this case: `var xscale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, w]).domain([0, 1])` which you can apply on `cx` this way: `.attr("cx", function(d) { return xscale(d[0]); })`. Same goes for the y-scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your code is producing the expected thing.

A central concept in d3 world are [scales (see this great intro](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/scales).)

Essentially you want to map your data from its extent to the space you're allocating (your SVG) through cartesian coordinates.

Your current x/y coordinates are 0.3px/0.3px.

By defining a scale that ranges from 0 to 1 and maps your values using the dimensions of your SVG, you are solving your problem:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,1])   // that's the extent of your data
  .range([0,w])    // that's how wide your SVG is
```

In an ideal world you would repeat this operation and define an `yScale` to calculate the y coordinates of your points.

This is a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3o1Lvgb/1/), have look.